# Limesurvey relational slider

Tags: slider, relational, limesurvey

I would like to create a slider where the answer of any item will influence the setting of the others.

An example:

```
I prefer my car to be...

cheap (slider ranges from 1 to 4)
environment friendly (slider ranges from 1 to 4)
luxurious (slider ranges from 1 to 4)
```

Its like a triangle relationship where the preference of 1 item sets a mark for the other ones. if you choose cheap and environment friendly with a high preference luxurious will have a low preference automatically. If you change luxurious back to high preference than one of the other markers gets changed again.

Is that somehow possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

When moving a slider, how will you decide which of the other sliders gets automatically adjusted?

You may be able to modify this workaround for dynamic sliders - https://manual.limesurvey.org/Workarounds:_Manipulating_a_survey_at_runtime_using_Javascript#Version_2.5x